# Calculating speed along point feature class (.gpx) in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, gps, gpx

I have imported a .gpx file into ArcMap as a point feature class.
Each feature has a Point z as well as a DateTime.
I want to create a graph that shows speed as a function of distance. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a presentation a few years ago where I developed a tool to take GPX points and create a line featureclass by rows where the *speed* is indicated as an attribute. You can symbolize the output by that field in ArcMap. Natural breaks seems to symbolize it well.

I just uploaded the tool to arcgis.com, you can [download it here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=46d7940511a74b9199cabceeede44aaa).

After you get the line, you can use the line as input to a graph from the View > Graph menu (in ArcMap). Or you can use the [Feature Vertices to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) tool to turn the line back into points with the speed attribute attached and turn those into a graph. Your value field will be *speed*

Alternatively, you can hack the script or write you own code as you know the most important part to finding speed: distance / time

Comment: Just out of curiosity - and I have not examined the code, but did you take in effect slope to calculate your true distance and therefore speed from point to point?

Comment: If you mean using the haversine formula, such as the one found here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html - then yes

Comment: No, the haversine formula is accounting for point to point travel over a sphere.  What I was referring to is how slope changes the distance between two points because it includes a third dimension. See [here](http://www.1728.org/distance.htm).  Essentially using Pythagorean Theorem from point to point.

Comment: Ah, I see. No, dont take that into account. Without any facts, my personal opinion is most time points are collected so closely together haversine and taking into account for slope wont change the final speed by anything of consequence.

Comment: That really depends on the type of travel being recorded.  Someone walking along a relatively flat surface, then yes I'd agree.  However, if someone is recording their trek over very rugged terrain, then the calculation of slope is really necessary.  Perhaps more so than haversine, IMO.

Comment: As someone who uses a consumer GPS in rugged/mountainous terrain on a regular basis, and looks at the speed being considered here, I'd have to agree with KHibma. Between the accuracy limitations of such a GPS unit in general and vertical in particular, plus the typical sampling frequency, any slope factor isn't really going to matter from point to point. Over greater distances/fewer sampling points, sure.

Comment: @evv_gis Interesting related read on this topic: http://sciencebasedrunning.com/2013/07/does-garmin-give-you-credit-for-the-vertical-distance-you-run/ (esp. last paragraph, and btw 200ft/mile = 3.8% grade). One of the steeper hikes with some convenient numbers around here is 1k feet over 1 mi. Taking into account slope on that hike, you travel an extra 93 feet over the mile (2% extra). Even doubling height gain to 2k (and that is *steep*), it's still only an extra 366 feet (or 7% of total distance).

Comment: @KHibma: thank you for creating and uploading this tool. It works fine. I might extend it to calculate the slope as a function of distance. Might be interesting when hiking/running to see how the slope affects the speed.

Comment: @Andy please do share your results if you enhance it. ChrisW had some interesting points but would be neat to see actual differences in the two outputs (if any, how much)